# How to assign a table name a variable's string value when created?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do this so that whenever someone registers, a table is created named "UserNameFriends."  This is my attempted code:

```
$friendstable = ("$username" . "Friends");
```

And the query:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "CREATE TABLE '$friendstable'
                               Friend VARCHAR(50) NULL,
                               FriendID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY");
```

However, when I test the code and register, the user's credentials gets inserted into my database, but a new table isn't created.

Comment: `However, when I test the code and register, the user's credentials gets inserted into my database, but a new table isn't created.` it's not possible with your shown code. show full code

Comment: remove the single quote  ('') around the variable.

Comment: For starters you should **never** update you schema structure with user supplied data. Try adding a column for username instead and only get data for the current user where that column matches their username.

Comment: @NickJ I already have a table containing the information of all users that registered.  Now I'm doing it so that each user has his/her own table filled with their friends.